# Break line in WinForms DataGrid for special characters (instead of white spaces)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I have a WinForms DataGrid. One column takes formulas from user (*like "1+55-var+4"*). The content of this column could be very long so I enabled text wrapping in that column.

```
myGridView.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
myGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
myGridView.Columns(5).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
```

That behaviour works perfectly for common text columns because the wrapping recognizes white spaces for line breaking.
But my fomula content does not have white spaces. I want that line breaks happen on special character (that means +, -, /, *) or if the column space overlaps.

Has anyone an idea? Thanks.

Comment: An workaround might be: You can replace special chars with special char + vbCrLf before setting the cell value (eg.: cellValue = cellValue.Replace(",", "," & vbCrLf))

Comment: You'd probably need to create a custom column type with a custom cell type and draw the text yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the text to wrap while the text box is being edited, the most straightforward solution would be to add and remove return characters yourself every time the TextBox loses focus or is resized. (Like G3nt_M3caj said) However, depending on the font figuring out exactly when and where to put returns might get messy.

Alternatively, everytime the TextBox loses focus find all of the special characters in the text and append & prepend the character with a Zero Width Space (U+200B).  And everytime the textbox gains focus find and remove all Zero Width Spaces.  You then don't need to even worry about the TextBox resizing.

If your making a digital button calculator, you additionally need to add the Zero Width Space before and after every special character like so:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   string key = ((Button)sender).Text; //A string containing the character that has been clicked.
    if ( '0' <= key[0] && key[0] <= '9' ) textBox1.AppendText(key);
    else textBox1.AppendText('\u200B'+ key + '\u200B');
}
```

On a final note, whatever you do make sure the text with Zero Width Spaces cannot be copied.  It would be a nightmare to debug code that somehow got a Zero Width character in it.

EDIT: I just realized you never said you were using a TextBox inside your DataGrid.  Well I think it will work either way.